# Problems with selection and postgresql/ sql checks

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a boolean selection that returns true only if the tests of the types 0,1,2, have a result greater than or equal to 60. The query does not cause me problems at the syntactic level but I can not get 1 from the result . What am I doing wrong?

```
   SELECT 1
    FROM resultTest r JOIN stuCLA s ON s.id = r.id_risultcla_studCLA
    WHERE s.matr = '12345'AND r.language= 'ENGLISH' AND r.lvl='B1'AND r.testtype=0 AND r.risult>=60 AND r.id IN 
    (SELECT  r1.id FROM resultTest r1 
    WHERE r1.language= 'ENGLISH' AND r1.lvl='B1'AND r1.testtype=1 AND r1.risult>=60 AND r1.id IN
    (SELECT  r2.id FROM resultTest r2
    WHERE r2.language= 'ENGLISH' AND r2.lvl='B1'AND r2.testtype=2 AND r2.risult>=60 ))
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want students who have taken all three levels and never have a score less than 60, then one method is:

```
SELECT rt.id_risultcla_studCLA
FROM resultTest rt
WHERE rt.language = 'ENGLISH' AND
      r.lvl = 'B1'AND
      rt.testtype IN (0, 1, 2) 
GROUP BY rt.id_risultcla_studCLA
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 AND MIN(rt.result) >= 60;
```